# React - Native tapping with keyboard on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a problem with Keyboard. In my app, I can not click the buttons (TouchableOpacity) while the keyboard is opened. I need to tap twice. The first tap is for closing the keyboard, and second is for tapping the button. Any idea on how to fix it? I can not find anything on google.

Comment: have you used TouchableOpacity in ScrollView?

Comment: Yes, I did use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this param `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'` prop to the ScrollView tag.

And Let me know it's work for you or not.